# different ways to create checkbox list in android

Tags: android, checkbox, checkboxlist

Could someone please explain the different ways of making checkbox list and saving the checked option? It would be nice if you could attach examples. I am using arraylist to save input, what are the other ways?

```
final CharSequence[] items = {};
final ArrayList seletedItems = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your ListItem object to have a 'checked' field

```
class ListItem{
boolean isChecked=false;
}
```

In your list adapter's `getView` attach a `onCheckedChangeListener` to the `CheckBox` and change the checked state of your object. something like:

```
final MessageItem Message=getItem(position);
        message.setText(Message.text);
        //set data

        select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); //important so that when reusing the view the old listener isn't called
        select.setChecked(Message.selected);
        select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Message.selected=isChecked;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class for objects like,

```
public class entity
{
  public boolean isChecked;
  //Any other variables can also be created
}
```

On check box selection change the value of

```
entityobj[index].isChecked=true/false;
```

Apply a custom list adapter,
in adapters getview() method you can check for isChecked value and then either check or uncheck the respective checkbox,
using this your selection will persist while scrolling also..
Hope it will help...

Comment: thanks but again i have to save all the selected items into an array right?? is there any other way to save the selected items??

Comment: What is exact issue you are facing??